# How do I securely store a .pem file when working with git-tracked heroku project?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, pem

I've got a git-tracked repo and am setting it up to work with APN for IOS push notifications. I'm looking at implementing the npm module [node-apn](https://github.com/argon/node-apn) in a similar way as [PushNotificationSample](https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample)

In this code, there is

```
var options = {
    gateway: 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', // this URL is different for Apple's Production Servers and changes when you go to production
    errorCallback: callback,
    cert: 'your-cert.pem', // ** NEED TO SET TO YOURS - see this tutorial - http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1
    key:  'your-key.pem',  // ** NEED TO SET TO YOURS
    passphrase: 'your-pw', // ** NEED TO SET TO YOURS
    port: 2195,                       
    enhanced: true,                   
    cacheLength: 100                  
}
```

However, how am I meant to reference my .pem files without committing them to Github?

At the moment, I'm deploying to Heroku.

Comment: I'm here for the same question, the best way to do that, finally, what did you do?

Answer (score 9):

Do this via Heroku's (environment) config variables.

If you're using node-apn or something similar, you should be able to [pass in the certificate and key content instead of a path](https://github.com/argon/node-apn/blob/master/doc/connection.markdown). Use ENV vars to pass in that the key content, as [recommended by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

```
cert: process.env.APN_CERT,
key:  process.env.APN_KEY,
passphrase: process.env.APN_PASSPHRASE,
```

Since you can't set multi-line values for app config in the web interface, you'll have to use the command line to set `APN_CERT` and `APN_KEY`:

```
$ heroku config:set APN_CERT="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> MIIDOjCCAiICCQCZTWzQNz6sqTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBfMQswCQYDVQQGEwJB
> VTETMBEGA1UECAwKU29tZS1TdGF0ZTEhMB8GA1UECgwYSW50ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0
...
```

Comment: Updated to suggest one answer that works for multi-line strings. If your APN library can't take a string and requires a file, write a temporary file from the string and pass that file to the library.